# Why do form control event names change when code is copied from a different project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events, boilerplate

Scenario is:

- I have a button called `X` in project A
- One of the events for `X` is the following:

  ```
  private void X_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {//if the user presses Ctrl + V 
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("hello");  
      }
  }
  ```
- I've now created a new poject B and added a button to a form and also called it `X`. I then copied the above code into `Form1.cs`.

Question: If I go to form B and select the button and then double click the `KeyDown` event it does not go to the code I copied in but creates the following. Why ?

```
private void X_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have neglected to copy the actual event binding, which is declared in your `Form1.Designer.cs` file. Something like

```
X.Click += new System.KeyDownEventHandlerEtcEtc;
```

Because this is missing, the studio thinks you're trying to create a new event handler. But because the default name for that event handler it tacks on a `_1`.

To overcome this, you can set the `Click` event in the designer manually to the specified, copied event handler. Or indeed any event handler with a matching signature.

Another way to do this is to not copy the entire event handler, but only the logic - then create a new handler in your new Form, pasting the logic there.

Comment: I believe you can also specify the name of the method to handle the event in VS as well.